# How do I pass a Google Calendar event via a Spring Boot Controller as the JSON Request Body?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scala, google-calendar-api

I am trying to pass a new calendar event to add a new event to a calendar. I pass the following JSON...

```json
{
    "summary": "My Event",
    "location": "201 w. 1st Ave Columbus, OH 43201",
    "description": "This is my first test event to the calendar",
    "start":{
        "dateTime": "2023-05-01T09:00:00-07:00",
        "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
    },
    "end":{
        "dateTime": "2023-05-02T09:00:00-07:00",
        "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
    }
}
```

I then try to write a controller that accepts the `com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event`...

```scala
  @PostMapping(path = Array("/calendar/event"))
  def addEvent(@RequestBody event: Event): Unit = {
    ...
  }
```

But when I run I get

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2023-04-30T14:49:41.718+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "path": "/google/calendar/event"
}
```

I think there is a way to use `@JsonComponent` and seperate `case class` but I haven't been able to get it to work. Is there a way I can pass a `com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event` as the request body? If not how would I do something similar with a `@JsonComponent` or is there a cleaner way? I would prefer to keep additional deps to a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Jackson was unable to deserialize the `start` and `end` fields into `com.google.api.services.calendar.model.EventDateTime` objects. Instead of accepting the request body in the controller as `com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event`, you could accept it as a custom object and then transform it into a Google Event. The custom class(in java) could look something like below:

```java
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.EventDateTime;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class InputEvent {
    private String summary;
    private String location;
    private String description;
    private EventDateAndTimeZone start;
    private EventDateAndTimeZone end;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class EventDateAndTimeZone {
        private ZonedDateTime dateTime;
        private String timeZone;
    }
    
    public Event toCalendarEvent() {
        Event calendarEvent = new Event();
        calendarEvent.setSummary(summary);
        calendarEvent.setLocation(location);
        calendarEvent.setDescription(description);
        
        EventDateTime startDateTime = new EventDateTime();
        startDateTime.setDateTime(new DateTime(start.dateTime.toEpochSecond() * 1000));
        startDateTime.setTimeZone(start.timeZone);
        calendarEvent.setStart(startDateTime);
        
        EventDateTime endDateTime = new EventDateTime();
        endDateTime.setDateTime(new DateTime(end.dateTime.toEpochSecond() * 1000));
        endDateTime.setTimeZone(end.timeZone);
        calendarEvent.setEnd(endDateTime);
        
        return calendarEvent;
    }
}
```

The `toCalendarEvent()` method in the custom class would convert the custom object into a Google Event object. You can invoke this method in the controller and then process the Google Event object as required.

```java
    @PostMapping("/calendar/event")
    public void addEvent(@RequestBody InputEvent event) {
        Event googleCalendarEvent = event.toCalendarEvent();
        LOGGER.info("Transformed event: {}", googleCalendarEvent.toString());
        // Process googleCalendarEvent
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom deserializer and annotate It with `@JsonComponent` annotation

```
@JsonComponent
class EventDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer[Event] {
  override def deserialize(jp: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): Event = {
    val node: ObjectNode = jp.getCodec.readTree(jp).asInstanceOf[ObjectNode]

    val summary = node.get("summary").asText()
    val location = node.get("location").asText()
    val description = node.get("description").asText()
    val startDateTime = node.get("start").get("dateTime").traverse(jp.getCodec).readValueAs(classOf[DateTime])
    val startTimeZone = node.get("start").get("timeZone").asText()
    val start = new EventDateTime().setDateTime(startDateTime).setTimeZone(startTimeZone)

    val endDateTime = node.get("end").get("dateTime").traverse(jp.getCodec).readValueAs(classOf[DateTime])
    val endTimeZone = node.get("end").get("timeZone").asText()

    val end = new EventDateTime().setDateTime(endDateTime).setTimeZone(endTimeZone)

    Event(summary, location, description, start, end)
  }
}
```

Here I have created a case class with the required fields

```
case class Event(summary: String, location: String, description: String, start: EventDateTime, end: EventDateTime)

@RestController
class TestController {


  @PostMapping(path = Array("/calendar/event"))
  def addEvent(@RequestBody event: Event): Unit = {
    println(s"Event: ${event}") // Event: Event(My Event,201 w. 1st Ave Columbus, OH 43201,This is my first test event to the calendar,{dateTime=2023-05-01T09:00:00.000-07:00, timeZone=America/Los_Angeles},{dateTime=2023-05-02T09:00:00.000-07:00, timeZone=America/Los_Angeles})

  }

}
```

Comment: How does this get to com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event?